# How to optimize rendering and tweening of many circle at once in unity?

Tags: performance, mobile, unity-game-engine, shader

I have a scene in which I render and tween multiple circles (from 7 up to sometimes 50 circle sprites) in unity, but it's hammering the frame rates on mobile. How can optimize this? Can I cull circles that are fully hidden behind other circles? Is there a circle shader that i can use that's efficient? Can I achieve the same effect differently?

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Maybe this might be useful for you: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html

Comment: You need to determine why exactly performance is low, only then optimize that part or ask about how to optimize it here. Randomly applying different optimization until it's fast is not a wise approach.

Comment: @GunnarB. - i believe, you don't have to occlude sprites that are simply behind each other: unity knows to not bother.